# Measuring variability in blood pressure in a repeated measures design with different time intervals between study visits

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, standard-deviation, dispersion

I have repeated measures on blood pressure for a lot of patients, measured at different intervals (table below).
I want my standard deviation to reflect that a large deviation in blood pressure measured over 1 year weighs heavier than the same deviation measured with 3 years in between. Is there a way to do this?

My data on blood pressure looks as follows:

| Study visit | Years between last visit | Systolic blood pressure | X-mean | (X-mean)^2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 135 | -11 | 121 |
| 2 | 1 | 145 | -1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 140 | -6 | 36 |
| 4 | 1 | 145 | -1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 165 | 19 | 361 |

Average systolic blood pressure: 146

Variance: 130

Standard deviation: 11.4

Comment: I don't know precisely what you mean by weighs heavier. If measurements taken closer in time have a higher correlation, you can use an autoregressive error structure or some other reasonable model. Then, you can take the standardized difference between two measurements within a subject $\frac{X_j-X_i}{\sqrt{V_{i,j}}}$ where $V_{i,j}$ is the estimated variance. Since you have in the model that  $V_{i,j}$ depends on the time lapsed between the two measurements, this will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a GEE model to predict change over time, but that was not entirely my question.

What I meant with 'weighs heavier' is that, using the table, the variation in blood pressure between the 2nd and 3rd visit (5 mmHg absolute difference) occurred over 3 years, while from the 3rd to the 4th visit the same absolute amount of variation occurred over less time (1 year). So the blood pressure variability per year is larger in the latter, but that is not reflected in just a 'normal' standard deviation of all the blood pressure measurements.